# Is there a function in R that reproduce the squeeze function of Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab

I'm looking for a function in R that reproduce exactly what the squeeze function of Matlab does. Does anybody know it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'd have thought that it would have been incumbent on an asker to explain what `squeeze` actually does -- drops singleton dimensions.)

See the help on the `drop` function in R; this also drops singleton dimensions.